# Is it dangerous to microwave formula if I swirl the bottle and test the temperature afterwards?

Tags: infant, feeding, formula, temperatures

The overwhelming consensus online is that microwaving a babies bottle can be "dangerous" because microwaving formula [can produce hot spots](http://similac.com/feeding-nutrition/formula-feeding/making-a-baby-bottle). However, if you simply swirl the bottle you can even out the heat distribution and eliminate said hot spots. The amount of bubbles produced by swirling is minimal and heat redistributes very easily in liquid. That being the case, if I test the formula's heat and its a good temperature, and the heat is redistributed, whats the big deal about microwaving the bottle? Is it just that people can't be trusted to swirl the bottle well and test the temperature?

Edit:

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the full articles, but for what its worth, here are a few articles which discuss the nutritional effects of microwaving formula and/or breastmilk (thanks to @[bestander](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/26221/bestander));

- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8889628 - Says there are no effects on B1/E/acids if the resulting average heat is not higher than 60 C
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11403146 - Reinforcement of first study results, showing no difference in B1/B6 levels if compared to stove top heating
- http://m.pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/89/4/667.short - E.coli bacteria grows faster in microwaved milk than control, i.e. antibacterial qualities are reduced
- http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/90/3/412.abstract - There is no significant loss of either riboflavin or vitamin C. Routine mixing resulted in formula temperatures which could safely be fed to infants. "portions reached a mean temperature of 44.7 C"
- http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2189981 - abstract is missing results

Comment: I'd be as much or more concerned about breaking down the nutrients in the formula.  Hot spots mean that you might have some portions at boiling at one point, which would denature proteins and might decrease the nutritive value of the formula.

Comment: For powdered formula, keep in mind that there is no damage done to the water when just heating the water prior to mixing, and mixing will certainly distribute the heat evenly.  If you must use a microwave to heat your formula, then simply heat the water in the microwave prior to adding the formula.  When you add the formula and mix it, you will have an evenly heated formula, and no damage from hot spots will have occurred to the nutrients.

Comment: @n00b Like I said, it's nothing special about microwaves, it's the nature of cooking, itself. Microwaves cook small portions of the formula, which is why heating methods are preferred to cooking methods.

Comment: Sometimes we would microwave a cup/bowl of *water* and put the bottle in that to heat it up. It's much faster than boiling water (never bothered with that), or running it under hot water (did that a lot).

Comment: I would think even if the portions that overheated lost some nutrition, hot spots are generally small and whatever effects of overheating would be limited to the contents of those little overheated pockets.  I would guess that if the bottle as a whole is not overheated, the vast majority of the milk heated was also not hot enough to loose nutrition.  Losing part of the nutrition in the small volume of the pockets that get overheated seems, well, not that drastic.

Comment: Relate: [Are there any studies about effects of microwave ovens on human breast milk?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/20095/are-there-any-studies-about-effects-of-microwave-ovens-on-human-breast-milk)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Noah & woliveirajr are both correct that there is some risk of reducing nutritional value, I'm sure.

I will offer as counter point my home study (sample size=2) of children who were bottle-fed formula almost exclusively as infants; formula which was on occasion reheated in the microwave. They are now 12 and 9, healthy, and not malnourished. They definitely suffer from one side effect often linked to formula feeding, which is being extraordinarily picky, bland eaters to this day. While the formula feeding may have contributed to that problem, I'm hard pressed to think how occasional microwaving of the formula would have made it worse - does killing nutrients also mean making it blander? Fail to nourish developing taste buds?

It's long enough ago that I don't have a firm recollection of just how often we did this. Certainly not all the time, but probably at least one feeding a day? But I could totally be making that up.

Comment: You're going to be an awesome part of this site, Thomas!  This is, of course, anecdotal evidence.  The question is, in all truth, too vague -- what the OP means by "ok" seems to be, "will it kill"?  My great grandmother chewed tobacco until she was 97 and laughed about it.  People have been using LSD for 76 years, many claiming no side effects.  What *is* ideal?  Just too hard to answer.  *What did I do and am still here to tell about?*  Much easier.  What's "ok"?... impossible to answer as there is no universal definition.

Comment: +1 At about 6 months I'd enough of trying to carefully heat night bottles for our son while stupefied from lack of sleep, and started microwaving them. I reasoned that any loss of nutrition would be minor given that at the time the recommendation was to make bottles with boiling water. After microwaving I'd shake the bejesus out of the bottle to mix everything up and negate any hot spots. We've a happy healthy little boy with no nutritional problems and no eating problems. I think the "don't microwave" directive exists because "people" en-mass can't be trusted to think sensibly, or at all.

Comment: I guarantee formula feeding **did not contribute** to them being bland eaters. Ours were breast fed for the first 6 months, but the last feed at night, from about 10 days old, was a bottle (to allow me to help, and my wife to sleep) and my kids eat everything. Literally. From the hottest spiciest chillies, to foods from all corners of the earth.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the formula that you're using, they might have some [probiotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probiotic) in their composition. For example, [Nestlé](http://www.nestle-baby.ca/en/products/formula/starter/goodstart_probiotic.htm).

Probiotics have small tolerance to high temperatures, so preparing the formula (or heating it after it was prepared) above some temperature might kill those probiotics, reducing the nutritional value of the formula. For example, [this preparation guide](https://www.nestlebaby.com.au/products/infant-formula/nan-pro-gold-1/) advises to use water at 40 degrees Celsius (after it was boiled and let to cool down).

Using the microwave might require you to have a control over this temperature (i.e., you should be sure it won't get higher than 40 degrees). If specific points of the formula over-heat, in that area those probiotics might die, but it doesn't mean that the whole formula lost it value.

Comment: I am not using a formula with probiotics. Do you have evidence to suggest that microwaving is destructive to some nutritional aspect of non-probiotic formula?

Comment: Excessive heat is destructive to nutritional aspects of all foods

Comment: FWIW from one of the studies I just posted; "bottles of varying colors were heated for 40 seconds and 60 seconds, respectively. Temperature profiling was monitored during the heating cycle.... Topmost portions reached a mean temperature of 44.7 ± 1.7°C and 43.0 ± 2.4°C for all types of 240-mL and 120-mL bottles, respectively. Topmost temperatures were significantly hotter than temperatures reached at other sites. Routine mixing resulted in formula temperatures which could safely be fed to infants (35.4 ± 0.3°C and 33.9 ± 0.2°C for 240-mL and 120-mL bottles, respectively)."

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, supplemental probiotics are [unlikely to be really beneficial anyway](https://sciencebasedmedicine.org/probiotics/).

Answer (score 5):

We microwave our infants formula all the time, it's all we use to heat the formula. We always swirl and double-check the temp before feeding. I disagree with the losing nutritional value statement. I don't think that warming milk to 20 degrees celcius is considered "cooking" to anyone. There is a fine line in microwaving time to go from feeding temperature to cooked milk, so you have to be careful and get used to it. But for us now we have the prep times all figured out. 4oz bottle 30 secs from the fridge, 19 secs from room temp for our microwave. Obviously times will vary from different devices. My wife and I had a "milk race" one night to see who could prepare the milk the fastest. She used the microwave, I used the bottle steamer. By the time my bottle was ready she had the baby half ways through the feeding with her bottle. Shame to say I lost. Typical husband I am...

Comment: You can also let it stand for a minute to help distribute heat. We did this with our kids, but never made the formula more than warm, and over time, made it less warm until we were actually serving it cold. There is nothing to say it has to be warm - it is transitioning from breast that makes it desirable for it to be warm.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not illegal, it's just ill-advised.

When it comes to your child's safety, is it really worth taking the risk? I believe a better statement would be **"During the heating or feeding process, no single part of the bottle or food should ever be hotter than what you would give to your infant"**.

Swirling the formula around to distribute the heat is explicit acknowledgment that some part of the formula will be hotter than others, and likely hotter than you'd give to your infant. Additionally, the bottle itself might be unevenly heated, and in that case, the heat will not equalize nearly as quickly.

Piggybacking on what Joe mentioned, you're also risking breaking down the nutritive value of the formula by microwaving it.

To counter your point re: microwave sanitization: When you sanitize bottles in a microwave, they're all pointing downward and draining any fluid (and chemical) buildup. When you're microwaving a bottle with formula, there's no such drainage, and any chemical buildup is absorbed by the formula.

### Potential Solutions

1. If you're using powder-mix formula, use warm water to mix instead of cold water.
2. If you're using full-strength formula, most don't need to be refrigerated, so they can stay at room temperature
3. If you're using a concentrate to mix pitchers and put the rest in the refrigerator, the best way to heat it is to run the body of the bottle under warm water, swirling the formula around so it all gets heated evenly.

Generally, if you have access to a microwave, you have access to hot water.

Comment: FWIW, we use powder, and pre-make (some) formula (boiled water) then store it. I would be interested to see any studies linking microwaving to destroying nutritional value, because it sounds possible, but unlikely I would think after 30 seconds of microwaving.

Comment: It's not necessarily the microwave itself that causes the loss of nutrients, but the small pockets of formula that could reach temperatures above recommended serving temperatures, and potentially above boiling point. Any cooked food loses some nutrients, but even/thorough heating to serving temperature through warm water isn't "cooking" in the same sense, but microwaving is, for at least some parts of the formula.

Comment: As for this: "Swirling the formula around to distribute the heat is explicit acknowledgment that some part of the formula will be hotter than others"... yes.  That is also why I stir my spaghetti sauce and black bean soup: some parts of it are getting hotter than others, even too hot in those spots to serve to adults.  So the stirring evens out the heat.  Sounds like a pretty tried-and-true technique when it comes to food... safe enough for my kids, at least.

Comment: It's also why health professionals and manufacturers of baby food products advise against microwaving formula. See notes regarding the loss of nutritive value in formula due to cooking.

Answer (score 1):

I would occasionally microwave a bit of formula, especially to take the chill off if we had placed an unused portion in the fridge.  (Yes, I will admit that publically... especially since I don't think my wife is on this forum... but I digress.)

One accommodation I made was this: I placed the bottle in a larger container, like a Pyrex measuring cup.  I filled the cup with water a bit higher than the level of formula in the bottle.  Then I microwaved the bottle in the surrounding water.  I figured this would act to moderate the rate of increase in temperature, and help even out the "hot spots" (if any).

Upon removing from the microwave, I would test the water in the cup (with my fingers) for its temperature.  If IT was not too hot, I figure there was a good chance the formula was not, either. I would then "swish" the bottle (as the OP mentions) and test it for temperature, too, by squirting on the wrist, or -- more reliably -- just tasting it.

Comment: Here's a good demonstration for exactly why that doesn't work to mitigate hot spots: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FhwTelc5Tg

Comment: The standing wave wavelength of microwave ovens is ~6.4cm. Add as much water as you want, it doesn't change the interference pattern

Comment: Thanks for the science demo.  Fortunately, my microwave does have a fully functional turntable, and thus my food (and baby bottle) moves in and out of all the "hot spots"  -- which was one of the very points of the video you cite.  Also, the water bath I propose does not serve to break up the standing waves but rather to act as a thermal mass to distribute the heat itself.  By the way, consumer-grade microwave ovens usually use a frequency of 2.45 gigahertz -- which has a wavelength of 12.2 cm, not 6.4.  But thanks for your concern.