# Stand or collar to hold bottle for warming in pot

Tags: bottle-feeding

Does something exists for bottle warming that is, essentially, just a collar that attached to the rim of a pot in order to hold a bottle upright while it is being warmed on the stove?

The real need: something hands-free, small or dual-use, and stove top. (Maybe a small double-boiler?)

Does this exist commercially (and what is it called)? It seems like a simple problem: what creative solution am I missing?

Comment: for approximately $16 USD, there is a dedicated hands free bottle warmer available from a few sources. I simply Googled 'hands-free bottle warmer'. If you don't want another appliance, how about fashioning a holder from a metal clothes hanger? You'd need to remember to use a pot holder, but it might work.

Comment: Interesting idea--and yes, as you say, hoping to avoid another appliance...

Comment: Why do you need to put the bottle on the stove at all? We heat water for two minutes in the microwave in a 2-cup pyrex measuring cup, remove it from the microwave, put the bottle in, let it sit for a minute, swirl, let it sit for another minute... and it's warm. No need for a pot on the stove at all.

Comment: @Catija yours is the answer for me, at least. I had been just heating water on the stove and then taking it off the heat/putting the bottle in, but the I've been using the microwave in almost the exact same manner as you suggest doing that for a couple of weeks and it works very well. So not "stove top" but with the same spirit: doesn't require attention (so I can start it and then attend to the baby and not worry about whether I am distracted) and neither does it require another gadget on the countertop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of @catija is the answer I would accept:

> We heat water for two minutes in the microwave in a 2-cup pyrex
>   measuring cup, remove it from the microwave, put the bottle in, let it
>   sit for a minute, swirl, let it sit for another minute... and it's
>   warm. No need for a pot on the stove at all.

Or using a mug (anything with handle) one-third filled with water. As long as you have a microwave:

- no extra gadgets needed
- can do one-handed
- can be safely left unsupervised (or forgotten about)
- heats to a consistent temperature

Answer (score 0):

You could try a steel cafetiere or a wide stove top infuser teapot.  An espresso maker would do if you could take out the middle spout.

The STEEL CAFETIERE is your best bet.

I don't know where you are but a quick search on Amazon in the US or Europe will produce lots of options, and even give you more ideas.

Answer (score -1):

why dont you just put in the microwave? No need to watch the pot.

Alternatively, in the UK you can buy an AC bottle warmer (essentially a bain-marie) that takes a little water and has a thermostat, I get that you're trying to avoid an extra appliance, but you can maybe sell it on ebay when you're finished?

Comment: They generally do not recommend using the microwave for warming bottles. See : http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/12712/is-it-dangerous-to-microwave-formula-if-i-swirl-the-bottle-and-test-the-temperat

Comment: as the article says, easily solved by giving it a quick shake. I dont see the difficulty in doing this, and it addresses every part of the asker's criteria